# WPA2 - EAPOL password exchange

Tags: security, wifi, wpa

(I'm doing this on my network, just for science). I was using airodump-ng to capture handshake. After that, I was able to open file with captured information in WireShark and find part with 4 handshake messages of EAPOL protocol. I know about millions of years needed for brute-force and I know that I can use aircrack-ng for dictionary attack.

I would like to extract just password from those 4 messages. I assume it is transfered as some sort of salted hash value. What I don't know is, in which message password resides (wireless password, for connection) and how exactly is sent? For example SHA1 of "password"+"ssid"... I would like to be able to compute exact same hash in my program (of course, that would be possible only for my network because I know my password). I'm gonna need that also for some demonstration on university.

Answer (score 2):

The 802.11i "4 way handshake" that you have captured is where both parties agree on shared Group (read: broadcast) and Pairwise (read: unicast) transient keys. I.e. the keys generated here only exist for the duration of the 802.11 Association, or until the next rekey is issued from the AP.

Before you can even begin to decrypt the 4 way handshake messages you need the pairwise master key (PMK), which is what gets derived from the user-entered passphrase using a key derivation function (PBKDF2), or is the result of a WPS exchange which is based on Diffie-Hellman.

The point here is the ASCII passphrase you are seeking to extract is not exchanged in any of the 4 messages, as it has *already* been shared amongst all parties involved in the transaction (client and AP in this case) and used to generate a 256 bit PMK. And unless you have this PMK, the contents of the 4 way handshake messages are as good as random data.

The best that you can do, if you already know the PMK, is extract the GTK and PTK from M2 and M3 of the 4 way handshake, and from those pull the temporal key which can be XORed with the payload in subsequent frames to get the plaintext data - which wireshark will also do for you if you enter the PMK or passphrase into the IEE802.11 settings and enable decryption.